# Is there any custom ROM that includes a feature to permanently kill a process?

Tags: custom-roms, ram, processes

As is well known from many blog/forum posts, Android 2.2 (Froyo) changed the mechanism for the API to kill the process such that a killed process will likely/possibly be re-started by the OS after being killed. E.g. there is no way to PERMANENTLY 100% guaranteed to stop an application from running short of un-installing it.

**Question:** Is there any code out there (likely part of some custom ROM) that allows permanent killing of a process without re-spawning it afterwards ala Android 1.6?

I'm mostly interested if such code exists, NOT whether it is in some specific ROM.

I don't much care about specific implementation way (I can think of at least two - either add a new API for "permanent kill" or provide a blacklist of apps that a modified AOSP API would respect).

**UPDATE:** Just to clarify - I am NOT looking for a way to prevent an app from being started again due to some event triggering an Intent that the app registered with. I am asking about preventing apps from being started by memory/process manager **just because it was recently killed**, even if that app has **no Intents registered** whatsoever, e.g. not listed in Autostarts app for any of the Intent types.

Please note that the above-mentioned notion of "restarting an app just because" comes from 2 sources:

- [Froyo help section](http://www.zomut.com/watchdog/froyo) for a well-regarded system app "Watchdog"

  > Google has changed the kill API that the task killers use. In 2.2 (Froyo), the kill API now just restarts the app. It will come right back, under a new system process.
- My own observations, where VERY frequently, my Droid X would have apps listed as running in ATK after I killed them, BUT those apps either don't have ANY Intents listed in Autostarts app, or all the Intents listed for them there are 100% disabled. Oh, and these are the types of apps (e.g. games) that are very unlikely to have a side daemon process responsible for reviving them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cyanogenmod ROMs has a feature that by LONG pressing the BACK button you can kill the running process.